# CSS Positioning: Fixed Left or Top when scrolling

Tags: html, css

I want to create scollable divs in html and css.

My goal is the following:
I have got three divs:

[image]

The orange div should stay at the top left.

When scrolling to the left or right (horizontal axis) I want the yellow pane as well as the blue pane to move left or right. The green and orange panes should not move left or right.

When Scrolling up or down (vertical axis) i want the green and blue pane to move up or down.The yellow and orange panes should not move up or down.

All the four divs are located in another div.

```
<div class="panes">
    <div class="orange"></div>
    <div class="yellow"></div>
    <div class="green"></div>
    <div class="blue"></div>
</div>
```

There is the Overflow css command, but I could figure out how to achive this.

Comment: You've stated a request,,,now what have you done to try and solve this for yourself?

Comment: can you share what you tried?

Comment: try this https://limpid.nl/lab/css/fixed/header-and-left-sidebar

Comment: I understand your requirement though you need to improve your question. You cannot done this just by using HTML and CSS. You need JavaScript too. Check for some column freezing techniques in internet.

Comment: What are the widths of the columns? how can you scroll blue and yellow if its responsive with 100% screen width?

Comment: on a side note @Amit the CSS in that URL is such bad practice with too much specificity

Comment: The yellow and blue divs are wider than the pane-div and the blue and green div are higher than the pane-div. 

It seems linke I will have to use JavaScript to achive this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now figured out a solution to this by using jquery:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <style>
    #content {
        position: fixed;
        height: 417px;
        width: 1000px;
        top: 5px;
        left: 105px;
        overflow-x: scroll;
        overflow-y: hidden;
    }

    #header {
        height: 50px;
        width: 3000px;
        background-color: yellow;
    }

    #appointments-container {
        height: 350px;
        width: 3000px;
        background-color: yellow;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }

    #appointments {
        height: 700px;
        width: 3000px;
        background-color: lightblue;
    }

    #legend {
        position: fixed;
        top: 55px;
        left: 5px;
        height: 350px;
        width: 100px;
        background-color: lime;
        overflow-y: hidden;
    }

    #topleft {
        position: fixed;
        top: 5px;
        left: 5px;
        height: 50px;
        width: 100px;
        background-color: orange;
    }

    #scroller {
        position: fixed;
        top: 55px;
        left: 1105px;
        height: 350px;
        width: 18px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }

    #scroller-content{
        height: 700px;
    }
    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div >
    <div id="topleft"></div>
    <div id="legend">
    <div id="legend-content">
        1 <br />2<br />3<br />4<br />5<br />6<br />7<br />8<br />9<br />10<br />11<br />
        11<br />12<br />13<br />14<br />15<br />16<br />17<br />18<br />19<br />20<br />
        21<br />22<br />23<br />24<br />25<br />26<br />27<br />28<br />29<br />30<br />
        32<br />33<br />34<br />35<br />36<br />37<br />38
    </div>
</div>
<div>
<div id="content">
    <div id="header">
        1 - 1 - 1- 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1- 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1- 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1- 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1- 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1- 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1- 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1- 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1- 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1- 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1- 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1- 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1- 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1- 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1- 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1- 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1- 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1- 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1- 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1- 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1- 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 
         - 1 - 1- 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1- 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1- 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1- 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1- 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1- 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1- 1 - 1 - 1 -
    </div>
    <div id="appointments-container">
      <div id="appointments">
         1 - 1 - 1- 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1- 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1- 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1- 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1- 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1- 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1- 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1- 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1- 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1- 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1- 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1- 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1- 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1- 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1- 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1- 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1- 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1- 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1- 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1- 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1- 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 
         - 1 - 1- 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1- 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1- 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1- 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1- 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1- 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1- 1 - 1 - 1 -  
        <br />2<br />3<br />4<br />5<br />6<br />7<br />8<br />9<br />10<br />11<br />
        11<br />12<br />13<br />14<br />15<br />16<br />17<br />18<br />19<br />20<br />
        21<br />22<br />23<br />24<br />25<br />26<br />27<br />28<br />29<br />30<br />
        32<br />33<br />34<br />35<br />36<br />37<br />38
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="scroller">
    <div id="scroller-content">
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#scroller").scroll(function() {
            var height  = $("#scroller").scrollTop();

            $("#appointments-container").scrollTop(height);
            $("#legend").scrollTop(height);
        });
    });
</script>
```

It is using the scroll event to capture when a pane is scrolled. And it uses scrollTop(height) to programmatically scroll the other panes.

Answer (score 0):

Use **OverFlow** As per your requirement.

**Example**: http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/vme2ejL1/2/

I created **4** div and apply **css** on it.

In **css** i used **overflow-x: scroll, overflow: scroll; overflow-y:
scroll;**

so instead of **scroll** you can use **auto** i.e  **overflow-x: auto, overflow: auto; overflow-y: auto;**

So when you use **auto** instead of scroll then scroll bar is not visible unit ll your text goes out side your div

**HTML**

---

```
<div class="panes">
    <div class="orange"></div>
    <div class="yellow"></div>
    <div class="green"></div>
    <div class="blue"></div>
</div>
```

**css**:

---

```
.orange {
    width: 30%;
    height: 93px;
    background-color: orange;
    float: left;
}
.yellow {
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
    height: 93px;
    background-color: yellow;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
.green {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: green;
     overflow-y: scroll;
}
.blue {
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: blue;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can only manage 1 scenario. Or scroll vertical with two div's or scroll horizontall two div's.

My example only focus on horizontal scrolling:
JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0tv5t3zo/

```
<div class="panes">
    <div class="orange"></div>
    <div class="green"></div>
</div>
<div class="right">
    <div class="yellow">
        <p>lorem ipsum dolar whatever lorem ipsum dolar whateverlorem ipsum dolar whateverlorem ipsum dolar whateverlorem ipsum dolar whateverlorem ipsum dolar whateverlorem ipsum dolar whateverlorem ipsum dolar whateverlorem ipsum dolar whateverlorem ipsum dolar whateverlorem ipsum dolar whateverlorem ipsum dolar whateverlorem ipsum dolar whatever</p>
    </div>
    <div class="blue"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.panes{
    float:left;
}
p{
    margin:0; 
    padding:0; 
    width:650px; 
    display:inline-block;
}
.orange{
    background-color:#FF7F27; 
    width:150px; 
    height:100px;
    float:left;
}
.yellow{
    background-color:yellow; 
    width:600px; 
    height:100px;
    float:left;
}
.green{
    background-color:green; 
    width:150px; 
    height:400px;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
}
.blue{
    background-color:blue;
    width:600px; 
    height:400px;
    float:left;
}
.right{
    overflow-x: scroll;
    width:600px; 
}
```

For what I know is it impossible to also make the green and blue div scrollable at the same time.